# Quel serait l'équivalent de « coin a term » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Quelle serait la manière la plus élégante de traduire « coin a term » ? Le terme est généralement utilisé pour décrire l'invention d'un mot ou une expression, en général utilisé dans un cercle privé par ceux qui l'ont inventé.

> They are known for their energetic live performances, having **coined the term "death jazz"** to describe their music.

ou

> **Ultra C is a word coined** by a Japanese play-by-play announcer covering the artistic gymnastics events at the 1964 Tokyo Olympic Games. It denotes a difficulty exceeding the score of C, the highest score at the time.

« Inventer le terme » ne me paraît pas restituer tout le sens de l'expression.

« S'approprier le terme » me paraît plus adapté mais pas totalement satisfaisant, avez-vous de meilleures suggestions ?

Comment: Il n'y a pas d'équivalent direct car cela reste une expression assez contextuelle. Mais des exemples existent sur Linguee : http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/coin+the+term.html

Comment: _« Inventé le terme » ne me paraît pas restituer tout le sens de l'expression_, quels aspects manquent-ils? Il faut vraisemblablement rappeler qu'il y a très rarement des traductions exactes et tout l'art de la traduction consiste à choisir les termes et expressions qui font le mieux passer l'intention de l'auteur original.

Comment: "inventé le terme", "inventé le mot", "inventé l'expression". e.g. "IBM a inventé le mot ordinateur".

Comment: @Archemar, c'est Jacques Perret qui à proposé le mot « ordinateur » à IBM. Il ne l'a pas vraiment inventé puisqu'il existait déjà.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La manière à la fois la plus « élégante » et la plus proche de l'anglais est probablement ***forger une expression*** (TLFI B.1.. On peut aussi utiliser ***créer*** et ***inventer***.

---

> ..., *having **coined** the term "death jazz" to describe their music.*
>
> ..., ayant **créé** l'expression « death jazz » pour décrire leur musique.

---

> *Ultra C is a **word** **coined** by a Japanese play-by-play announcer*
>
> *Ultra C est une **expression forgée** (ou **inventée**) par un commentateur sportif* japonais

Remarque: On ne peut pas dire « **un mot** » puisqu'il y en a deux ici.

---

Answer (score 2):

J'aime bien l'expression *On doit le terme à* (cf. Anglais *we owe the word to*), qui transmet la même quantité d'information. Un cas classique en traduction où *on* a pour équivalent une tournure passive en anglais.

Comment: Tournure intéressante. Je prends note.

Answer (score -1):

Je me souviens avoir souvent entendu:

> Pour reprendre ses dires « ... »

Ou encore

> Jean a utilisé l'expression « ... »

Ou encore:

> D'où le terme « ... »

Ce qui peut expliquer un terme nouveau ou plutôt une nouvelle expression (souvent en français on écrit des expressions plutôt que juste un mot.)

Traduire la phrase offerte pourrait se faire de la façon suivante à l'écrit:

> Le mot (l'expression, la phrase) "Ultra C" est entrée dans le langage depuis les jeux Olympiques de Tokyo en 1964.

Moi j'ai jamais entendu, mais il y a aussi:

> Le néologisme "Ultra C" à été forgé (ou inventé) à Tokyo.

Un autre cas, en parlant quelqu'un qui veut utiliser une nouvelle expression pourrait dire:

> « Ultra C », si vous me permettez (ou passez) l'expression.

Comment: -1. Je trouve la réponse trop approximative et dépourvue d'explications correctes au profit de -> "Moi j'ai jamais entendu"

Comment: +1 pour avoir proposé différentes facettes d'une expression traduite montrant les choix et difficultés de la traduction, La présentation est à revoir, en supprimant le point de vue du rédacteur et en indiquant les contextes de traduction : préciser par exemple que la dernière proposition relève du langage familier.